Has There Been a Change in Bitcoin RPC's scriptPubKey Address Field
So I have not been very into Bitcoin for a long time. My seniors worked on Bitcoin RPC methods in my project back in 2018-2019. At that time, the response of getblock was fetched, then we fetched the transaction from the response, and from the tx_hash, we used to fetch vout, then scriptPubKey, and from that, the old team fetched addresses. There used to be many addresses back then maybe. But now, in 2024, when I worked on it, I found that there is no addresses field in scriptPubKey, but instead, it's address, only one.
So I just want to confirm if there have been any changes, and is there are any docs related to this changelog, as I tried to find it myself but didn't find any.

Once you know the bitcoind version this code was written for and the bitcoind version you are using now, you can go through the release notes available here to learn about any breaking change.
